# Reload Webpage in BrowserTab and not ALL Webpages - Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, reload

I have some BrowserTabs open with the same Webpage.
I will reload ONLY in the open Tab reload the Page, not in all Tabs if the same URL open.

```
location.reload('true')
```

reload ALL the same Pages.

Answer (score 0):

might be possible duplicate, but combine document.location.reload() with the content of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: Can you help me with this? JavaScript is still new territory for me.